# How do I Make and Use React components?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, es6-modules, es6-class

I'm trying to understand how to create (export maybe?) and use (import ?) components in a React application? For example, the small React app below is an .HTML file and runs fine. It displays random numbers over and over. So, if I wanted to put the class ShowRandomNumbers extends React.Component into a separate file (with an extension....of what .JSX?) and use it in an HTML file with an import statement, what steps would I need to do?

I'm used to the concept of using external JS and CSS files, like:

```jsx
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.38/browser.js"></script>
```

and

```jsx
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/base200.css" />
```

but those files I simply create with a simple editor and Save-As standalone files.    I've Googled about export default and import, and I see syntax like
export default App; and import App from './App.jsx';  But no clear "how to."
Do I need utilities to create the JSX file?

Step by step would be appreciated.
Thank You.

```jsx
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>79E - ALL CDN</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class ShowRandomNumbers extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {  super(props);  }  

  render() {
    var elapsed = Math.round(this.props.timeNow  / 100);
    var seconds = elapsed / 10 + (elapsed % 10 ? '' : '.0' );
    var r1 = this.props.random1;

    return ( 
    <p >Running for  {seconds} seconds.  Random 1 is:  {r1}   Random 2 is:  {this.props.random2}      </p >
    ); 

  }  // render -- END
}  // Class - End

var start = new Date().getTime();

setInterval(function() {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <ShowRandomNumbers 
        timeNow={ new Date().getTime() - start  } 
        random1= { Math.floor(Math.random() * (500 - 100 + 1)) + 100 }
        random2= { Math.floor(Math.random() * (600 - 100 + 1)) + 100 }
      />,  
      document.getElementById('container')     
    );
 }, 50);
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.38/browser.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A jsx file cannot be used directly, browsers don't understand jsx files. You need to transpile it to a js file. You may use [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react) for this task.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've been looking at babel and npm etc.. 
Re import/export, it seems to me (maybe wrong) that the import is kinda, well , fake! In that webpack smooshes everything together into a single module, so there's no "real" dynamic loading. Like say, .dll in a Window OS which loads when needed. In which case, isn't it just like a regular script statement? <script> says load this JS with the HTML page, even if I don't actually call any funcs defined in the JS file. Unlike .dll which gets loaded when a call is made. (That ofcourse would slow the page as it waits for JS to load.)

Answer (score 1):

In order to take advantage of import/export, you need to use a module bundler. [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) is the standard choice for React applications. Basically, this allows you to export components (and other javascript functions, constants, etc) from one file and import them into another file and use them. Webpack builds up a dependency graph by analyzying your imports/exports, starting from your root application file. It bundles all of the necessary code together and gives you a file that you can include via a script tag, like you are used to.

Learning how to setup a project with Webpack can be a little daunting and a stumbling block for a lot of people. If you are just starting out with React, I would strongly recommend checking out [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). It gives you a modern React development environment without having to worry about any of the configuration yourself.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Helps alot. I was erroneously mixing technologies. Here's what I think is the issue.
1) import/export is an ES6 features. (Nothing to do with React)
2) The actual under the covers support for import/export is NOT in browsers (at least not yet.) See URL below re: ES6.
3) So, other technologies are required to make import/export work, like WebPack.

I find this kinda odd. Like Toyota promoting features like brakes, but leaving it to someone else to implement. I see glossy ads about brakes and assume they come with every Toyota. 

create-react-app. I will look into this.

Comment: Yeah, that's sort of the reality of modern frontend development; it's not specific to React. Even though modern browsers do have pretty good compatibility with ES6 features, you still generally have to transpile your code (using Babel) to ES5 for legacy browser support.

So there is a bit more initial setup cost, but the tradeoff is worth it for the significantly improved developer experience. create-react-app was made specifically to counteract that initial setup cost and get you up and running. Understanding all of these tools is important, but it's usually not what you want to start with.